# Mask 404 page URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I've setup a 404 ErrorDocument handler in my htaccess file, and it works fine. However, the address bar reflects the filename of that file. I'd like to use mod_rewrite to mask the actual filename and replace it with something else while still actually displaying the file.

Here's my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^404.php$ /error/404 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own... Rather than using the 404.php file in the ErrorDocument handler, I used the fake url, then added a rewrite rule to rewrite the fake url to the 404.php file (but without redirect).

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
RewriteRule ^error/404$ /404.php [L]
```